# what to do with a question, which isn't a question but a tutorial?

Tags: discussion

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33095599/3145341) question, which isn't a question but a tutorial, I am not sure if I should raise this as *off topic* or *unclear what you're asking*.
While I do believe this doesn't follow Stack Overflow guidelines but I also believe there will be many visitors who might find this helpful.

So, the question I have is should we flag, down vote and delete such posts or just keep it (archived, locked or something) considering this might be helpful to someone else ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it's not a question, it should be (and has been) closed.
Stack Overflow is not a blog to post tutorials at.

What the OP probably should have done, is to post a *good* question on how to do what the tutorial explains, so he can self-answer *that* question with the tutorial.

Comment: I agree. Now that the post has been put on hold, will this post be deleted eventually or will it stay ?

Comment: Since it has no answers, a score of `0`, and is closed, I believe it should automatically be removed eventually.

Comment: Just curious to ask, can a user intent on sharing a tutorial, by asking a question and then stick the tutorial to share as answers?

Comment: @amuse: That's an option, yes. However, the question will have to be a good one. Another option would be to find a good question where that tutorial can be an answer.

Answer (score -8):

Create question and tell your friend to reply with tutorial style

Comment: Yea, nope. That's not how SO works.

Comment: To clarify: You can answer your own questions. No need to get a friend to do that.