# How to flag a non-useful question with a tutorial-like self-answer

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I ran into this question in Triage: [What is a span tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413817/what-is-a-span-tag).

The user posted the question acting like they have researched, and don't understand this HTML attribute. The user then answers the question as if writing a tutorial.

I believe it should be closed and deleted. The answer to this question can be found very easily.

What would be the best way to proceed? There doesn't seem to be a relevant close vote option, and the question has only received two downvotes. Is downvoting the only option in this case (and choosing Looks OK for the review)?

Comment: What makes you so sure the question (and answer) are not useful? If the answer can be found easily here, mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: Because the answer can already be found with a single Google search. It is the very basics of HTML. Why does Stack Overflow need to house yet another tutorial that can be found already?

Comment: If there isn't a relevant close vote option, ***maybe it shouldn't be closed***.

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time I had to decline a flag on these by pointing someone to ["Encyclopedia Stack Exchange"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/)...

Comment: That question seems too broad, it's not asking (at least not clearly) about anything specific.  The Q&A seems woefully incomplete compared to [all this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[html]%20span%20tag).  Based on the answer, it seems they were thinking mostly of the difference between `div` and `span`, and what those are for, and there's a nice duplicate for that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/183532/400617.

Comment: @KevinB I guess I'm confused as to why the SO community is strict sometimes but not other times

Comment: @BradLarson [This post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309693/1585362) was one of the main reasons why I thought a flag was the proper thing to do.

Comment: @Jack - Note that that answer was about a question that wasn't a question at all, not a question that had a tutorial as an answer. How this is structured can matter.

Comment: The irony of not doing your research before posting on meta to complain about a post not doing its research is not lost on me.

Comment: @Jack The SO community is strict not only on the questions/answers it contains, but also the enforcement of correct flagging/downvoting procedure. SO draws a very fine line between a question being off-topic vs a question being bad, and the difference is often jarring for newer(-ish) members such as you or me. I've only recently come to understand that heavily downvoted posts do not necessarily warrant a flag/closure/deletion, and that some highly upvoted posts do.

Comment: @Servy I wasn't complaining about lack of research, but rather asking what I should do as a reviewer. I have researched this sort of thing, but have found it difficult to find a consistent answer to the question. Yes downvoting seems obvious, but I wanted to make sure I shouldn't do more.

Comment: @Jack There is lots of information on meta on the topic of whether or not questions should be closed for a lack of research.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=close+research

Comment: @Servy As I said, lack of research was not what I was asking about. Lack of usefulness (maybe because it is already well documented) on the site was more what I was wondering about.

Comment: @Jack And have you even looked at the help center for the most fundamental guidelines of when you should vote to close a post, and what the close reasons are?  You'll notice that there isn't a "not useful" close reason.

Comment: I like how this question is getting downvoted and you're getting pushback, but the question you refer to is downvoted, closed and now deleted.  But then, I like watching the world burn.

Comment: @Servy Yes I have. I wasn't sure what to do in this specific case. That is why I asked about it. Not everything is documented specifically.

Comment: related: [Tried to add a self-answered wiki-post, but just got downvotes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251874/tried-to-add-a-self-answered-wiki-post-but-just-got-downvotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is downvoting the only option in this case (and choosing Looks OK for the review)?

If you really think the question isn't useful, downvoting is the only option. That's exactly what's the purpose of downvotes is.

Answer (score 1):

Asking and answering your own question is allowed, and indeed *encouraged* on SO (that's why there's a button for it on the "Ask Question" page). You may argue that this particular question isn't very good, but the general idea of asking and answering a question with a "tutorial-like self-answer" is valid.

The tooltip on the downvote button makes it clear what it means. In particular, it lists "unhelpful" as a reason to downvote.

Comment: I'm not asking if answering your question is allowed, I'm asking how I can Vote to close the question as being unuseful or if downvoting is the only option.

Comment: @Jack: The question isn't one that should be closed. Perhaps downvoted, but not closed.